# How to solve `A network-related or instance-specific error...` while runing Live example of Telerik

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Hi;

Last day i'm tried to start with a simple reporting web project in `ASP.Net`, after many times of searches and examines different `jQuery` charting plugins, i'm found Telerik useful for my project. so i'm downloaded the latest version of Telerik controls. then i'm installed it on my PC and get's to run demo. but when i'm run Live example of Telerik, i'm see this error:
[image]

How can i solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solved my problem. I'm search this problem on `google` and other forums, but couldn't find an answer. so, i'm get to the installation path of Live demo and opened the `.sln` file. then `Visual Studio` reported me an error that this application needs to `SQL Server Express` that currently is not installed on this system. so, i'm downloaded the latest version of `SQL Server Express` from `Microsoft` site and installed it and now every thing works fine.

**You can download `SQL Server Express` from** [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)